# Firebase Invalid or expired token how can ı solve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase to verify User but when i send to token front-end to backend ı take a error. I research little and most people say is your machine time problem. And I Checked My country time is İstanbul(GMT+3) Lets say 14:42 but firebase clock is for auth 11:42 there is 3 hours delay but firebase token valid only 1 hour.When i try the my local machine time the same as firebase but also ı take same error ı couldn find any solution aynone help ? My react is 100% is true not related the code issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVIFJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxJPF.png)
[image]

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Please copy and paste the error into the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check if your backend and front-end are pointing to the same firebase app, because you're talking about a token expiration error that could not happen because this GMT time from firebase is equivalent to your GMT+3 time
[(see image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAjRp.png).